# Why is %pylab not starting pylab mode?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am simply trying to plot a diagram of one variable as function of another by reading them from a LibreOffice Calc sheet and running Python through terminal in the newest Ubuntu version. Here is my short `test.py` file:

```
%pylab
# import mesa_reader
import mesa_reader as mr

# load and plot data
h = mr.MesaData('LOGS/history.data')
plot(h.log_Teff, h.log_L)

# set axis labels
xlabel('log Effective Temperature')
ylabel('log Luminosity')

# invert the x-axis
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

The problem is, the terminal gives the following problem when I type `python3 test.py`

```
File "test.py", line 2
    %pylab
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone tell me what my issue may be here?

**Edit: Here is the new code**

```
# start pylab mode
# %pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import mesa_reader
import mesa_reader as mr

# load and plot data
h = mr.MesaData('LOGS/history.data')
plt.plot(h.log_Teff, h.log_L)

# set axis labels
plt.xlabel('log Effective Temperature')
plt.ylabel('log Luminosity')

# invert the x-axis
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

However, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

**Edit 2: Here is the code + error**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mesa_reader as mr

# load and plot data
h = mr.MesaData('LOGS/history.data')
plt.plot(h.log_Teff, h.log_L)

# set axis labels
plt.gca().xlabel('log Effective Temperature')
plt.gca().ylabel('log Luminosity')

# invert the x-axis
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 63, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
  File "/home/nick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
```

Comment: `%pylab` is an ipython magic command only: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pylab

Comment: Is there an equivalent command for running pylab mode in linux, or would I have to try something else?

Comment: I will post the problem by editing my post

Comment: Oops, let me try your code you submitted

Answer (score 0):

`%pylab` is an ipython magic command only: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pylab

To make this work you have to slightly rewrite your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mesa_reader as mr

# load and plot data
h = mr.MesaData('LOGS/history.data')
plt.plot(h.log_Teff, h.log_L)

# set axis labels
plt.xlabel('log Effective Temperature')
plt.ylabel('log Luminosity')

# invert the x-axis
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

To save the file you can do:

```
plt.savefig('my_plot.png')
```

Comment: No good, got ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'```

Comment: Should I install the newest version of python? See edit 2 in my post.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why you're getting that particular error, but you should use Python 3 instead of 2.

Comment: HI, so now I am getting AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlabel'

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnick, I complete the edit, run the same `python test.py` command again. No errors, but no plots show up either.

Comment: Oh, you can do `plt.show()` or `plt.savefig('my_plot.png')`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Now I am going to try to learn more about matplotlib. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Matplotlib, in my opinion, is a great thing to learn more about. Best wishes.